# chunksOf and string datatype

Tags: haskell

I'm in need of a function to convert a string like 'Hello World' from the console to an Integer , and convert the Integer back to a string.

```
import Data.Text (Text, chunksOf)

encodeInts :: String -> Integer
encodeInts = read . concatMap show . map ord . show
decodeInts :: Integer -> String
decodeInts = read . map chr . map read . chunksOf 2 . show
```

The encoding works, in `decodInts`  however, I'm getting:

> ```
> * Couldn't match type `Text' with `[Char]'
>   Expected type: Integer -> [String]
>     Actual type: Integer -> [Text]
> * In the second argument of `(.)', namely `chunksOf 2 . show'
>   In the second argument of `(.)', namely
>     `map read . chunksOf 2 . show'
>   In the second argument of `(.)', namely
>     `map chr . map read . chunksOf 2 . show'
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Text'
>   Expected type: Integer -> Text
>     Actual type: Integer -> String
> * In the second argument of `(.)', namely `show'
>   In the second argument of `(.)', namely `chunksOf 2 . show'
>   In the second argument of `(.)', namely
>     `map read . chunksOf 2 . show' Failed, modules loaded: none. Prelude>
> ```

I have already tried using `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`

Comment: I'm confused - what is wrong with just `show` and `read`?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning: I need to convert strings like `Hello` to its integer representation, not just strings like '123'

Comment: Which `chunksOf` do you use?

Comment: @Zeta I'm using `chunksOf` from Data.Text

Comment: Well, there's your problem. A `Text` isn't a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because `chunksOf` has the wrong type:

```
chunksOf 2 :: Text -> [Text]
```

Either use `chunksOf` from `Data.List.Split` or write your own:

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
chunksOf _ [] = []
chunksOf k xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt k xs 
                in as : chunksOf k bs
```

That being said, your function won't work. `ord 'o'` is `111`, a three digit number. I would write simpler variants:

```
encodeInts :: String -> [Int]
encodeInts = map ord

decodeInts :: [Int] -> String
decodeInts = map chr
```

After all, the process to get `[Int]` from `Integer` is ambigous, even with                fixed lengths, since the first character might have an `ord` less than 100.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have ASCII (or at least no unicode) and no zero `Char`s in your string, you can use this

```
encodeInts :: String -> Integer
encodeInts = foldr (\c n -> n * 256 + toInteger (ord c)) 0
decodeInts :: Integer -> String
decodeInts = map (chr . fromInteger) $ takeWhile (> 0) $ map (`mod` 256) $ iterate (`div` 256)
```